# Two threads using same variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
private void stopThread() {
    thread1.canRun(false);
}

private void createThread() {
    thread1.stopThread();
    thread1.canRun(true);
    thread1 = new Thread(thread1);
    t.start();

}
```

i have only one button.
when i click the button i execute the threads which counts to n number
when i click the button again the last thread should stop and create a new one.

the problem is when i create second thread it seems that last one doesnt stop and both keep running

```
  @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= TimeOut && canRun; i++) {
             System.out.println(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            }

        }

    private volatile boolean canRun;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in these lines:

```
thread1.stopThread();    // <-- sets canRun to false
thread1.canRun(true);    // <-- sets canRun to back to true
```

You could also initialize `canRun` with true, which would mean that thread is runnable in it's initial state:

```
 private volatile boolean canRun = true;
```

Comment: From your code excerpt it looks like your `canRun(true)` sets back the `thread1.stopThread()`. So you could try just removing this line.